# Variables should be defined but aren't

Tags: python, variables, undefined

I'm completely new to Python and have been taking tutorial scripts and tinkering with them to see what I can do but I'm running into some trouble. The variables red and green come up as undefined which I'm not sure why they would be? Also don't know if this is the best way to go about changing a color from a key press so any help and improvements would be much appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
import keyboard


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        red = True
        green = False
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('g'):
        green = True
        red = False
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            if red == True:
               Color(1, 0, 0)
            elif green == True:
                Color(0,1,0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))


class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: They "come up as undefined" in which context? "But they should be?" Why do you believe so? Where you have written, for example, `if keyboard.is_pressed('r')`, *when* do you expect the code to check whether the `'r'` key is pressed?

Comment: "don't know if this is the best way to go about changing a color from a key press" This isn't a clear enough explanation of what you want to happen. You have to think through the logic. What exactly should happen when you press the key - does that change the colour of previously drawn ellipses, or of the ones that will be drawn in the future, or just what?

Comment: Those variables are defined at the class level -- they aren't visible as local variables in instance methods.  To access them from an instance method, put `ClassName.` in front of the variable, i.e. `MyPaintWidget.red` or `MyPaintWidget.green`.

Comment: If you are "completely new to Python" then you should not be trying to make graphical programs. This introduces a lot of complexity and confusion that you don't need right now. There are fundamentals that you should learn first. Look for a general Python tutorial first. The stuff you are finding right now, probably assumes that you're already at a level where you could answer this question yourself, or better yet not run into the problem in the first place.

Comment: If all else fails, the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) includes a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
    red = True
    green = False
elif keyboard.is_pressed('g'):
    green = True
    red = False
```

This section of code is not defined in any method of this class.
Therefore these variables will never be defined as the class body is executed only at startup, not after main starts running, and you keyboard won't catch any keys being pressed later on.

`red` and `green` do not exist unless something makes the code enter this if or else indented lines. So for sure you will get runtime errors if you try to access them in the on_touch method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is calling `on_touch_down()`, but you should move your *red/green* setting code:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
        red = True
        green = False
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('g'):
        green = True
        red = False
```

into the top of the `on_touch_down()` method so that it gets called before trying to execute your code that depends on them.

Comment: I had it in the on_touch_down() method before and that worked, but it meant I had to click while pressing the key to change the color.